# exclude 1 image optimization from image-webpack-loader webpack

Tags: webpack

https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-webpack-loader

i use this loader module for images optimization , but I have 1 svg with animation ,when webpack optimize it , it seems broken , is it possible to exclude this image optimization (only 1 image) ?

```
export default new WebpackConfig()
  .extend({
    '[root]/browser.js': config => {
      config.module.rules
        .find(l => l.test.toString() === regex.images.toString())
        .use.push({
          loader: 'image-webpack-loader'
        })

      return config
    }
  })
```

below you can see my code snippet

Answer (score 1):

```
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require('image-minimizer-webpack-plugin')

export const imageMinimizePlugin = new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
  test: regex.images,
  exclude: [PATHS.activeMenuAnimateSvg]
})
```

found another plugin which gives the opportunity to make it

Comment: So image-webpack-loader isn't capable of this as far as you know? It's pretty annoying for images that you manually put a gradient over, or anything out of focus as it seems to over compress it - which is kind of annoying :)